# Convergent in $C([0,\pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Which of following sequences $\{f_n\}$ are convergent in space $C([0,\pi])$

1. $f_n(x)=\sin (nx)$

2.$f_n(x)=\sin ^n (x)$

3.$f_n(x)=\sin (\frac{x}{n})$

My answers:

1. It's not convergent. For example for $f_{2n-1}(\frac{\pi}{2})=(-1)^{n+1}$.
2. Couldn't find counter example. Not sure of the answer.

3.We know that $\sin(t)\le t$, so $\sin (\frac{x}{n}) \le \frac{x}{n}$, so it's convergent to $f(x)=0$.

Could you point me if my thinking is correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe $f_n(x)=\sin ^n (x)$ converges pointwise to 1 in multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2} $ and to $0$ otherwise...

Comment: So it's not convergent, because function $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1, otherwise =0 \notin C([0,\pi])$?

Comment: it is not uniformly convergent, but I would say it is pointwise convergent

Comment: As $n$ increases, all functions $f_n(x)=\sin ^n (x)$ seem to go to $0$ when $x$ is different from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so they seem to converge to the constant function $f(x) =0$ (who does live in $C([0,\pi])$) While $f_n(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1$ for all $n$, so $f_n$ converges to the constant function 1, in that point.